# Dart & SQFLite & DatabaseException

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

i'm new on Flutter/Dart, on my code i'm retrieving some data from a table and map it to a List
My code works fine but i'd like to Handling errors & exceptions so i tried to use DatabaseException 
This is my code:
[image: my code]
I know that maybe the question is basic but i don't understand
why list is no valid inside `"if (e.isNoSuchTableError()) {"`

Thanks for help

MM

Comment: ok thanks, understood !
i add code as screenshot only because i'd like to show errors with red arrows :)

Answer (score 1):

The `list` is defined inside a `try` block, which means its not in the scope of the `catch` block, that's why you cannot access it inside the `catch` block. You need to define it outside the `try` block to be able to access it:

```
List<Map> list = null;
try {
 list = await db.rawQuery(cmd);
} on DatabaseException catch(e){
   //access it
}
```

The same concept is used in methods:

```
void getData(){
  List<String> listOfNames =  List<String>();
}

void retrieveData(){
  print(listOfNames); // Undefined name 'listOfNames' - line 10
}
```